# Which version of JHipster is supported by the JHipster Blueprint generator?

Tags: jhipster

Here is the link to the generator's repo : https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster-blueprint

So I am trying to develop a blueprint. I have followed the steps in the readme for local development. When I try to run "jhipster -d --blueprints TestQuestion", this is the message I get :

```
DEBUG! Found blueprint generator-jhipster-TestQuestion and server with namespace jhipster-TestQuestion:server
WARNING! Error adding current blueprint templates as alternative for JHipster templates.
Error: The Namespace jhipster-TestQuestion:server may not be correct. Please check your configuration and ensure your blueprint folder start with "generator-". Detail: Error: Error parsing namespace jhipster-TestQuestion:server
    at module.exports.jhipsterTemplatePath (/home/dev/Documents/JavaProjects/JHipster/generator-jhipster/generators/generator-base.js:201:13)
    at new JHipsterBaseBlueprintGenerator (/home/dev/Documents/JavaProjects/JHipster/generator-jhipster/generators/generator-base-blueprint.js:68:49)
    at new JHipsterServerGenerator (/home/dev/Documents/JavaProjects/JHipster/generator-jhipster/generators/server/index.js:65:5)
    at new module.exports (/home/dev/Documents/JavaProjects/JHipster/generator-jhipster-Test/generators/server/index.js:7:9)
    at Environment.instantiate (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/environment.js:801:23)
    at Environment.create (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/environment.js:773:17)
    at JHipsterServerGenerator.composeWith (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/index.js:1326:42)
    at JHipsterServerGenerator._composeBlueprint (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/generator-base-blueprint.js:516:43)
    at async JHipsterServerGenerator.composeWithBlueprints (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/generator-base-blueprint.js:413:34)
    at async JHipsterServerGenerator._postConstruct (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/server/index.js:96:7)
ERROR! jhContext.setupServerOptions is not a function
TypeError: jhContext.setupServerOptions is not a function
    at new module.exports (/home/dev/Documents/JavaProjects/JHipster/generator-jhipster-Test/generators/server/index.js:18:19)
    at Environment.instantiate (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/environment.js:801:23)
    at Environment.create (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/environment.js:773:17)
    at JHipsterServerGenerator.composeWith (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/index.js:1326:42)
    at JHipsterServerGenerator._composeBlueprint (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/generator-base-blueprint.js:516:43)
    at async JHipsterServerGenerator.composeWithBlueprints (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/generator-base-blueprint.js:413:34)
    at async JHipsterServerGenerator._postConstruct (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/server/index.js:96:7)
    at async JHipsterAppGenerator.compose (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/app/index.js:431:11)
(node:183468) [DEP0148] DeprecationWarning: Use of deprecated folder mapping "./generators/" in the "exports" field module resolution of the package at /home/dev/Documents/JavaProjects/JHipster/generator-jhipster-Test/node_modules/generator-jhipster/package.json.
Update this package.json to use a subpath pattern like "./generators/*".
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
```

https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster-blueprint/issues/225
This issue asked the same question, but one year ago. It said that the blueprint generator did not support JHipster v7 at the time, and so that's why it did not work.

Which brings me to my question : **Which version of JHipster is supported by the JHipster Blueprint generator?**

I have JHipster 7.8.1, so if you also know how to downgrade my version, I would appreciate it a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The blueprint generator was added in JHipster [v7.7.0](https://www.jhipster.tech/2022/02/27/jhipster-release-7.7.0.html) so you should be fine to use it with 7.8.1. You can check out the following recently-released blueprints that are based on 7.8.1.

- https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster-native
- https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster-ionic